# setOnTouchListener и setOnClickListener одновременно. Нужно чтобы после ACTION_MOVE не срабатывал setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
        private int initialX; 
        private int initialY; 
        private float initialTouchX; 
        private float initialTouchY; 


        @Override 
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
            switch (event.getAction()) { 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 

                    initialX = params.x; 
                    initialY = params.y; 
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX(); 
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY(); 
                    return false; 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                    return false; 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX); 
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY); 
                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(button, params); 
                    return true; 
            } 
            return false; 
        } 
    }); 

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View arg0) { 
            two(); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Если в `ACTION_MOVE` выставить `True , то все равно срабатывает`setOnClickListener`. Как сделать так, чтобы если кнопка изменила координаты не срабатывал клик?

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать сделать так, создать класс

```
public class SingleTapGestureDetector implements 

GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return false;
}
}
```

а затем `gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext, new SingleTapGestureDetector());`

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            two();//не будет срабатывать при свайпе, но будет работать при обычном клике
        }

switch (event.getAction()) { 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 

                initialX = params.x; 
                initialY = params.y; 
                initialTouchX = event.getRawX(); 
                initialTouchY = event.getRawY(); 
                return false; 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                return false; 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX); 
                params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY); 
                mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(button, params); 
                return true; 
        } 
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Так как у меня уже public class FloatingViewService extends Service   , то создавать class SingleTapGestureDetector бессмысленно. Я добавил интерфейс сразу к своему классу  public class FloatingViewService extends Service implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener . Всё работает , но нету звука от щелчка нажатия на кнопку ))) А так спасибо) Выходит я использую интерфейс созданный для идентификации жестов?

Answer (score 1):

Я пробовал так , использовав флаг Move. Все работает , но если я двигаю , то всё равно отыграет звук щелчка, клик произойдет, но не будет выполнено ничего. Как вариант.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
        private int initialX;  
        private int initialY;  
        private float initialTouchX;  
        private float initialTouchY;  


        @Override  
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {  
            switch (event.getAction()) {  
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  

                    initialX = params.x;  
                    initialY = params.y;  
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();  
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();  
                    return false;  
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  
                    return false;  
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);  
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);  
                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(button, params);  
                    Move = false; 
                    return true;  
            }  
            return false;  
        }  
    });  

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View arg0) {  
           if(Move){ 
                two(); 
            } 
            Move = true; 
        }  
    });
```

}
 Какие еще разумные варианты есть?